# Returning pointer on vector of pointers from C++ dll to Python

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, dllexport

I have successfully returned pointer to struct(that contains `wchar_t*`) from c++ dll into Python like this:
C++ code:

```
...
typedef struct myStruct{
    wchar_t* id; 
    wchar_t* content; 
    wchar_t* message;
} myStruct;

DLLAPI myStruct* DLLApiGetStruct(){
    myStruct* testStruct = new myStruct();
    testStruct->id = _T("some id"); 
    testStruct->content = _T("some content"); 
    testStruct->message = _T("some message");
    return testStruct;
}
```

Python code:

```
class MyPyStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("id", c_wchar_p),
        ("content", c_wchar_p),
        ("message", c_wchar_p)
        ]
...
...
myDLL = cdll.LoadLibrary('myDLL.dll')
myDLL.DLLApiGetStruct.restype = POINTER(MyPyStruct)
result = myDLL.DLLApiGetStruct().contents
print result.id, result.content, result. message# those are valid values
```

Ok, that works fine, the **PROBLEM** is that now I need to return pointer on vector of pointers to those structures. I've tried this:

C++ code:

```
typedef std::vector<myStruct*> myVector;
...
DLLAPI myVector* DLLApiGetVector(){
    myVector* testVektor = new myVector();
    for(i=0; i< 5; i++){
        myStruct* testStruct = new myStruct();
        testStruct->id = _T("some id"); 
        testStruct->content = _T("some content"); 
        testStruct->message = _T("some message");
        testVektor->push_back(testStruct);
    }
    return testVektor;// all values in it are valid
}
```

Python code:

**#I think that first and second lines are incorrect (is that proper way to make restype??):**

```
vectorOfPointersType = (POINTER(DeltaDataStruct) * 5)  #5 is number of structures in vector
myDLL.DLLApiGetVector.restype = POINTER(vectorOfPointersType)
vectorOfPointersOnMyStruct= myDLL.DLLApiGetVector.contents
for pointerOnMyStruct in vectorOfPointersOnMyStruct:
   result = pointerOnMyStruct.contents
   print result.id, result.content, result.message
```

Values in last row are NOT valid - it's some random parts of memory I guess.
This is error I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-11: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `vector` is C compatible, but you need to pass the C caller (or ctypes) the address of the first element. That said, you'd have to hold on to the pointer to the `vector` to free it later. I think you'll be better off using an array from the start. You can pass the function an `int` out parameter to receive the length of the array. Since you're using `new` to allocate, remember to catch a `bad_alloc` exception should the allocation fail.

Personally, I'd use an array of structs instead an array of pointers, such that the data is in single contiguous block. This yields a cleaner interface in ctypes. With an array of pointers you have to dereference twice to get at the struct.

C++:

```
#include <new>
#include <cwchar>

typedef struct myStruct {
    wchar_t *id;
    wchar_t *content;
    wchar_t *message;
} myStruct;

const wchar_t ID[] = L"some id";
const wchar_t CONTENT[] = L"some content";
const wchar_t MESSAGE[] = L"some message";

DLLAPI myStruct **DLLApiGetArray(int *size)
{
    int i, n = 5;
    myStruct **result;
    try {
        result = new myStruct *[n];
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            myStruct *tmp = new myStruct();
            tmp->id = new wchar_t[wcslen(ID) + 1];
            tmp->content = new wchar_t[wcslen(CONTENT) + 1];
            tmp->message = new wchar_t[wcslen(MESSAGE) + 1];
            wcscpy(tmp->id, ID);
            wcscpy(tmp->content, CONTENT);
            wcscpy(tmp->message, MESSAGE);
            result[i] = tmp;
        }
    } catch (std::bad_alloc &ba) {
        *size = -1; return NULL;
    }
    *size = n; return result;
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *

class myStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("id", c_wchar_p),
        ("content", c_wchar_p),
        ("message", c_wchar_p)
    ]

myDLL = cdll.myDLL
myDLL.DLLApiGetArray.restype = POINTER(POINTER(myStruct))
myDLL.DLLApiGetArray.argtypes = [POINTER(c_int)]

n = c_int()
p = myDLL.DLLApiGetArray(byref(n))
n = n.value
```

Example looping through the result:

```
>>> for i in range(n):
...     print i, p[i][0].id
...
0 some id
1 some id
2 some id
3 some id
4 some id
```

---

FYI, it's incorrect to use the `_T` macro with explicit `wchar_t` arrays. That's for Microsoft's `TCHAR` type, for compiling as ANSI vs Unicode. Use `L"wide character string literals"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for example code, it works perfectly. Can you explain to me why there is `[0]` in `p[i][0]`?

Comment: `p[i]` is a pointer. You have the option to use `p[i].contents` or to get the 0th element. Like I said, I'd rather use an array of structs. In that case `p[i]` would be a `myStruct` instance. But I'd have to rewrite the code to do it that way. I figured I'd present it closer to what you already had.

Comment: Can you suggest me how and at which point should I free memory. I have to do that because of `result = new myStruct *[n];` , right?

Comment: Export another function to free the memory. It needs parameters for the array and its length. Loop through the array to `delete[]` the `wchar_t` arrays for each struct and then `delete` the struct. Finally, `delete[]` the array itself.